# How to get random documents from Elasticsearch indexes with 50 million documents each

Tags: elasticsearch, random

I'd like to sample 2000 random documents from approximately 60 ES indexes holding about 50 million documents each, for a total of about 3 billion documents overall. I've tried doing the following on the Kibana Dev Tools page:

```
GET some_index_abc_*/_search
{
  "size": 2000,
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
          "field_a": "some phrase"
        }
      },
      "random_score": {}
    }
  }
}
```

But this query never returns. Upon refreshing the Dev Tools page, I get a page that tells me that the ES cluster status is red (doesn't seem to be a coincidence - I've tried several times). Other queries (counts, simple match_all queries) without the random function work fine. I've read that function score queries tend to be slow, but using a random function score is the only method I've been able to find for getting random documents from ES. I'm wondering if there might be any other, faster way that I can sample random documents from multiple large ES indexes.

EDIT: I would like to do this random sampling entirely using built-in ES functionality, if possible - I do not want to write any code to e.g. implement reservoir sampling on my end. I also tried running my query with a much smaller size - 10 documents - and I got the same result as for 2000.

Comment: two sets of double quotes at the start of your "size" property might be an issue, if you directly copy/pasted.

Comment: This means your query is too heavy for the cluster to handle. To check this assumption, run the same query on a single index. You might also want to test this with a smaller `size` as well.

Comment: To pick 2,000 records from 50,000,000 you could try [Reservoir Sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservoir_sampling).

Comment: Fixed the syntax error (wasn't the cause of the problem - I had added it in after running the query) and clarified requirements.

Comment: you were able to do something about it?

Comment: No, I haven't found a solution to this issue yet.